# truffle version and solcjs --version returns different versions

Tags: solidity, truffle, solc

I want to change solc version on my system(downgrade from 0.5.16 to 0.4.17). I tried uninstalling it with

```
npm -g uninstall solc
```

and then installed with

```
npm -g install solc@0.4.17
```

but it does not work, "truffle version" still returns "Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)" when I run it from my CMD. However when I run

```
solcjs --version
```

separately, the correct version is returned - `0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.Emscripten.clang`

How can I change solc version on my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truffle installs its own internal version of solcjs.

If you're on Truffle 5.x, then you can configure it (after the installation) to use a different compiler for the various commands that it provides (`truffle compile`, `truffle test`, `truffle deploy`, etc).

In your Truffle configuration file (`truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js`), add this section:

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
        version: "0.4.17",
        optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean solcjs will use `0.4.17` as well as the default version?  solc can be changed on the fly using `$ solc-select install 0.5.0` then `$ solc-select use 0.5.0`. I couldn't change the version on the fly with solcjs so I just use `solc --abi x.sol -o build`